# How do I tell which modules have been mixed into a class?

Tags: ruby

I have a class that has a number of modules that are mixed in with it based on some runtime criteria.

I want to be able to get a list of which modules have been mixed into this class. How can you do that?

UPDATE

So when I said class I meant object as it is the object that is being extended at runtime using:

```
obj.extend(MyModule)
```

obj.included_modules and obj.ancestors don't exist so you can't get the modules that have been mixed in from there.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Try:

```
MyClass.ancestors.select {|o| o.class == Module }
```

for example:

```
>> Array.ancestors.select {|o| o.class == Module}
=> [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

UPDATE

To get the modules mixed into an object instance at runtime you'll need to retrieve the eigenclass of the instance. There is no clean way to do this in Ruby, but a reasonably common idiom is the following:

```
(class << obj; self; end).included_modules
```

If you find yourself using this a lot, you can make it generally available:

```
module Kernel
  def eigenclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end
```

and the solution is then:

```
obj.eigenclass.included_modules
```

Comment: There is a ready-made method for that, called `included_modules`.

Comment: Turns out I jumped the gun. I have upated the question with some more details.

Comment: Readers note, this answer is from 2009. Ruby 1.9 introduced `Object#singleton_class`, which is identical as the monkey-patched `Kernel#eigenclass` implementation above.

Answer (score 39):

This might be a better idea:

```
MyClass.included_modules
irb(main):001:0> Array.included_modules
=> [Enumerable, Kernel]
```

Answer (score 23):

If you're looking for the whole list, [Swanand's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328068/how-do-i-tell-what-modules-have-been-mixed-into-a-class/1328241#1328241) is your best bet.

If, on the other hand, you want to check whether a class includes a *particular* module, the `<` operator is your friend:

```
module Foo
end

class Bar
  include Foo
end

Bar < Foo
# => true
```

Answer (score 20):

```
obj.singleton_class.included_modules
```

And if you want to check if module included:

```
obj.singleton_class.include? MyModule
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is definitely now the preferred way to test this.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another effective way to see if a module has been *included* or *extended* by a class.

As others have mentioned, you can determine whether a module is included on a class by checking the `included_modules` class method that exists on all classes in ruby.

So if you had a class named `MyClass` and you wanted to see if it *included* the `Comparable` module you could do something like this:

```rb
# will return true if MyClass.include(Comparable)
MyClass.included_modules.include?(Comparable)
```

If you want to determine whether your class has *extended* the `ActiveRecord::Querying` module, as all rails model classes do, you can actually use this:

```rb
# will return true if MyClass.extend(ActiveRecord::Querying)
MyClass.kind_of?(ActiveRecord::Querying)
```

Why does this work?  To quote the book [Eloquent Ruby, by Russ Olsen](http://eloquentruby.com/):

> When you mix a module into a class, Ruby rewires the class hierarchy a bit, inserting the module as a sort of pseudo superclass of the class.

This also means that another way to determine whether a module has been *included* into your class is to do something like this (although I still prefer the `included_modules` method):

```rb
# will also return true if MyClass.include(Comparable)
MyClass.new.kind_of?(Comparable)
```

Answer (score 3):

Only classes can story methods and when you add a method to an instance you are actualy adding it to the objects metaclass. The module you are looking for will be in this metaclass ancestors list.

```
module TestModule; end

obj = "test"
obj.extend(TestModule)

class Object
  def metaclass
    class << self; self; end
  end
end

obj.metaclass.ancestors
# => [TestModule, String, Comparable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 2):

I like @AlexParamonov's solution, but I played around and found out that this works just as well:

`obj.class.include? MyModule`

`MyClass.include? MyModule`

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-include-3F

Comment: Unless you modified the singleton object. For example: `a = []; a.extend(MyAwesomeModule)`. In this case `a.class.included_modules` will not include `MyAwesomeModule`, but `a.singleton_class.included_modules` will